# View FreeRTOS tasks control block in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, freertos

Is there a way to view all of the FreeRTOS tasks control blocks in visual studio?

The normal "Threads" view doesn't shows that and I didn't find any other view for it?

Answer (score 0):

OK. found it, it was a silly question.
I'll post an answer anyway for anyone else who get stack on it.
It is in "debug" -> "windows" -> "Live Watch" -> "FreeRTOS" -> "threads"